# regex for this string in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have these rows:

```
db666405.gallery
db666405.table1
db666405.table2
```

I want to capture the word after the dot.

How to do with regex in mysql?

I have tried with `^\.` or `[.]`, but I did not succeed.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `column` REGEXP '^\\.'
```

Comment: so you only want to capture the value preceeding `.gallery`?

Comment: NO i want capture the value gallery

Answer (score 2):

MySQL regex doesn't "capture" anything. It's for *matching* only; there is no support for regex replacement in MySQL.

I assume you want to return the part after the dot:

```
select *, substring(`column`, instr(`column`, '.') + 1) as ext
from `table`
where `column` like '%.?%'
```

Comment: How does `instr` differ from `locate`? Is one more backward/foward compatible?

Comment: Compatible in MySQL versions?  They probably exist in all versions.  Compatible with other RDBMS products?  I doubt it; cross-vendor compatibility anywhere in SQL is an unfulfilled dream.

Answer (score 0):

To select any columns that have the word Gallery, you can use a

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `column` LIKE '%gallery%' `
```

This will return all that have `gallery`

Comment: sorry this is only an example but i have more row that the word gallery change like this db666405.gallery, db666405.table1, db666405.table2 . i want to capture the word after the dot

Comment: YOu can use a site such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test regexes. `^.+\.(.+)$` will work because the parenthesis say to start after the period on what is captured

Comment: You can't `capture` in mysql.

Comment: ^.+\.(.+)$  It works with PHP but with MySQL does not work 
$re = '/^.+\.(.+)$/'; <br>
$str = 'db666405.gallery';

preg_matchl($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);